# How to create a executable jar file for Testng and the runnnig point should be the Xml file

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, jar, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on the selenium web driver and testng on Eclipse IDE. I usually run the test from the XML file that i have created which runs all the methods in the eclipse.

Now i want to create a simple executable jar which should do the same i.e its running point should be the XML file so that each test is executed .

I am trying hard on this. Please give me some advice on how to go further with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Eclipse Export Wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-33.htm). While exporting, select "Create Runnable Jar" and select the class which is **entry point** (which contains `main` method) of your project.

This class will have `main` method which will read XML and execute the testcases

Comment: Getting unable to find testng.xml when run from command prompt. XML is  in my runnable jar. Any help??

Answer (score 39):

Here is the better way to do it. But thanks anyways sanbhat.

You can just create a main method which will have list of all test classes to be executed as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { test_start.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
}
```

Here is the reference URL from the official testng website.

http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Cheers!

Comment: To use an xml configuration instead of directly choosing classes to run, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23287848/116810

Comment: I did this to start testNG when Javafx button is clicked. It works in eclipse but doesnt work when application is deployed as Jar file.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a main method like below and can execute it

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
    suites.add("c:/tests/testng1.xml");//path to xml..
    suites.add("c:/tests/testng2.xml");
    testng.setTestSuites(suites);
    testng.run();
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer since it was about running an xml file

Answer (score -4):

Creating a jar File in Command Prompt

Start Command Prompt.
Navigate to the folder that holds your class files:

```
C:\>cd \lalit
```

Set path to include JDK’s bin.  For example:

```
C:\lalit> path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;%path%
```

Compile your class(es):

```
C:\lalit> javac *.java
```

Create a manifest file and your jar file:

```
C:\lalit> echo Main-Class: hitech >manifest.txt
C:\lalit> jar cvfm hitech.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

or

```
C:\lalit> jar cvfe hitech.jar hitech *.class
```

Test your jar:

```
C:\lalit> hitech.jar
```

or

```
C:\lalit> java -jar hitech.jar
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated