# Export Selenium TestNG script from Eclipse to runnable jar

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a script written in Selenium using the TestNG framework. This script executes via an xml file. Since we do not have main method in this, how can I export this script to a runable JAR file?

Comment: What IDE do you use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a executable jar file for Testng and the runnnig point should be the Xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393223/how-to-create-a-executable-jar-file-for-testng-and-the-runnnig-point-should-be-t)

Answer (score 0):

I marked this question as a dupe (and this code snippet comes from the dupe question), but basically you could write a public static void main method that scans for tests or loads a existing testng.xml file.  Then, you just need to use something such as Maven Shade plugin to package it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
TestNG testng = new TestNG();
testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { test_start.class });
testng.addListener(tla);
testng.run();
}
```

I used WebDriverManager project to manage my driver libraries. I would have the .jar load those externally.

Comment: I tried it also but getting "Command line suite" in the console and nothing else.

Comment: Just read the TestNG documentation.  There are also other similar examples around the web.

Comment: Thank you Everyone. I have got the solution for this.