# How to run unit test as jar file or exec file automatically on android device without using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, automated-tests, appium

I have written unit test with `appium` which run successfully on android real device through Android studio. Now I want this unit test as a jar or `exe` file so that test will run automatically from my machine to android device connected to it via USB whenever my server invokes it. Is it possible to do this?
    Also I have tried to generate `jar` of it but it is not working. How `jar` can be run as a program from desktop to device attached to it. Or could there be any another way to run my test program automatically on android device from desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by calling main method under @Test annotation so that I can run this class as a java application. Then convert it into runable jar. After that using Launch4j convert it into exe. From webAPI server call this exe which run successfully. I have taken solution from this answer ->
[How to create a executable jar file for Testng and the runnnig point should be the Xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393223/how-to-create-a-executable-jar-file-for-testng-and-the-runnnig-point-should-be-t)