# Exploring options to deliver Selenium test to non-tech business team who wish to run the test on their own

Tags: selenium, testng, pom.xml, extentreports

Our non-technical business team need to run only 1 automation test script which will be fetching data from several hundreds rows of Excel file. I've created automation that script using a Maven project (with POM framework and Extent Report), using Selenium WebDriver, Java, TestNG, and Eclipse but not sure how to deliver the test/script to the business team. Would appreciate if you guys can suggest a few options to deliver this script to the business team so that they can change few parameters in Excel file and run the script on their own. I'm getting Extent report at the end of the test, would be best if they can get the Extent report as well.

Note: Since they are non-technical, it is preferable to avoid installing and configuring Java, Eclipse, etc tools on their machine but that's not mandatory so I'm open to check several options.

Comment: Export your script to runnable jar file and create a bat file to run the jar file. Your business team has only to install java (doable even for bfu) and run the bat file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to suggest few options here :

1. **Jenkins** - Install it on Any server and share login and url with them. They can execute build and no technical knowledge required.
2. **Executable JAR** - Export your project as executable JAR and deliver that JAR file. All they have to do it , Double click on JAR file OR execute via batch file and it should run that script and get done the job. Make sure all data related file should be there with JAR. i.e excel file

**Note :** They always need JAVA in the machine regardless of what they prefer from above to use.

Comment: You can include the Java run-time in the build....  (So you don't necessarily need the end-user to install Java.)  I'd recommend using a server for running remote-webdriver jobs.  That way you only need to maintain one set of webdrivers.

Comment: @Helping Hands: For Executable JAR. Using the `TestNG` annotation in my test, I wasn't even seeing my test file listed under "Launch configuration" drop-down in "Runnable JAR File specification" - so can't create `Runnalbe JAR` using `TestNG`.  This way I can have Extent Report but can't have `Runnable JAR`.

In order to create `Runnalbe JAR` I had to remove all `TestNG` annotations ..but then I don't get Extent Report.

I really appreciate your precious reply but will keep looking for the solution of having a `Runnable JAR` or EXE or any other option with the colorful Extent Report.

Comment: Sure. This might help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393223/how-to-create-a-executable-jar-file-for-testng-and-the-runnnig-point-should-be-t

Answer (score 0):

Usually i used to give as batch file script, if you have jenkins, integrate your bat file in it. other wise share the batch file as it is.

1. Create a package JAR,
2. Create .bat file to execute the JAR.